# Two questions about possible mysql and php functionalities (maybe javascript?), and where I should look to learn more

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

First, is it possible for when I insert a record onto my mysql table, a page is automatically generated using the new record in some way. EXAMPLE: My column "image" is on autoincrement, so my image names are always numbers. Furthermore, is it possible for when I insert a record, I automatically generate a page with my image name. So basically, I submit record 367, the image name is 367, and my site will automatically generate mysite.com/367? I want to go in more details but you get the point. Is it possible? If not, what's the closest thing possible?

Also, is there someway to automatically update my page periodically. Such as I set it so at 5pm, it'll automatically insert a code. 5:30pm, it'll insert a different code, which I preprogrammed to do. This is useful, for say I'm on vacation but I still want to update my site regularly.

Can you guys point me to any specific tutorial/terminology/methods/programs/codes/anything? All help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Code I have so far (just want to show to Nick)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>tgh</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("thegoodhumor");
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM gallery";
        if (!isset($_GET['Page']))  $_GET['Page']='0';
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);

        $Per_Page = 16;   // Per Page

        $Page = $_GET["Page"];
        if(!$_GET["Page"])
        {
            $Page=1;
        }

        $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
        $Next_Page = $Page+1;

        $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
        if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
        {
            $Num_Pages =1;
        }
        else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
        }
        else
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
            $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
        }

        $strSQL .=" order  by GalleryID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
        $objQuery  = mysql_query($strSQL);
$cell = 0;
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1"><tr>';
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
  if($cell % 4 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }

if($cell == 2) {
    echo '<td>RESERVED</td>';
} elseif ($cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>The other cell</td>';
} else {
    echo '<td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/imagetitle/' . $objResult["Picture"] . '" />' .
    $objResult["GalleryName"] . '</td>'; }
    $cell++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
    ?>

        <br>
view more:
<?php
        if($Prev_Page)
        {
            echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'>prev</a> ";
        }
            {
                echo "|";
        }
        if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
        {
            echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>next</a> ";
        }
        ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: yes, but your not creating pages, one script uses the id probably from the url to send what ever output you want. for the 2nd bit, look up cron jobs.

Comment: Thank you! I'll definitely look into cron jobs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a dynamic web page.  To make a dymaic webpage I'd suggest using PHP which would interact with the mysql server.

For example, a user would visit 'mysite.com/info.php?image=367' and the php script would get the information 'image=367'.  Your PHP script could do a select query against the mysql database 'SELECT paragraph FROM table WHERE image_id = 367' and then write that data out to the user's web browser.

As far as the user is concerned they just visited 'mysite.com/info.php?image=367', but in the background, PHP dynamically created the webpage content after it got that request.

More basic info about dynamic webpages: http://way.clicktracks.com/help/en/pr650/index.html?dynamicwebsiteshowtheywork.htm

Simple Intro to PHP:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp

Here is a head start I wrote for you, feel free to use it.

```
<?php

  if (!isset($_GET['imageNumber'])) 
    die("You must specify an image number");

  $image_requested = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['imageNumber']);  //sanitizes input

  $dbhost = 'localhost';    //TODO: Set this to the ip address of your mysql server if it is not on the same machine
  $dbuser = 'root';     //TODO: Set the username you use to access your mysql db here
  $dbpass = 'password';     //TODO: Set the password you use to access your mysql db here

  $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ('Error connecting to mysql');

  $dbname = 'database_name_here';  //TODO: Set the database name here 
  mysql_select_db($dbname);

  $query = "SELECT paragraph FROM table_name WHERE image_id = " . $image_requested; //TODO: Set table_name, column to get, and image_id to the correct column name

  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error());

  echo "Here is the paragraph of text" . $row['paragraph'];  //TODO: Set paragraph to the same column you retrieved 3 lines above.

  mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

As for the second part of your question, it can also be done with PHP

```
<?php

$specifictime = strtotime("tuesday 3pm");
if (time("now") > $specifictime)
{
 echo " its after 3pm on tuesday"; 
}
else { 
 echo " not 3pm on tuesday yet"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: don't believe anything on w3schools

Comment: @Dragon I added a tizag link for you

Comment: I already know some about php, passed the level of tizag and w3schools I think... is there a more specific tutorial regarding the first question?

Comment: goggleing "php dynamic website" found a few thousand, cant be more specific than that not really knowing your needs.  you could of course look at something pre-built.

Comment: I added some basic PHP code that should get the image they want, connect to your mysql db, get the associated paragraph and output the paragraph text.  By modifying this slightly you could also get the location of the image and output an image tag ala "<img src..."

Comment: Hah, I actually already have a start. I edited my original post to show you my current code. Now, I just want a to somehow automatically generate a page (with the record and my site layout) whenever I enter in a new record. Can you help me out with these info?

Comment: It looks like you already have a PHP implementation, your basically saying that you would rather simply create a bunch of static webpages each time you enter a record into your DB? Such a question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668666/when-a-new-row-in-database-is-added-an-external-command-line-program-must-be-inv

Comment: Thomas, did that answer your question, if so you can go ahead and mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hi sorry, I had to make a quick errand, and completely forgot about this topic until now. I actually think Dagon helped me more since he made me interested in the word 'dynamic' (I thought any page with .php is considered dynamic); after looking into it, I figured it out. The link's answers you provided seems too dangerous and will cause too much headache. Nevertheless, here's a check! as your link does eliminate my original intention expressed in my original question