# How to execute external script/app/command from MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to share a discovery that has helped me a lot. This is the plugin for MySQL UDF which can run bash scripts and commands from MySQL. In my case it was very interesting to create triggers associated with a particular table.

- Download from : https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/archive/master.zip
- Open the folder and edit Makefile:
- We will install some compilation tools
- `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
- `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev`
- If you can not install the latest tool from the repository, do `sudo apt-get update` to update them.
- Add `-fPIC` In the command gcc to compile the plugin us.
- Modify *LIBDIR* variable to point to your mysqld plugins folder, usually:
- `LIBDIR = / usr / lib / mysql / plugin`
- `make`
- `./Install.sh.`
- Already installed but disabled. To enable:
- `sudo Ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/`
- `sudo Apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`
- to verify the installation, you can run from the MySQL console:

  > SELECT sys_eval ("id")
- if it returns something like:

  > uid = 122 (mysql) gid = 130 (mysql) groups = 130 (mysql)

  the installation is *successful*

I hope you find it useful.

References:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-23-5-1-11

http://jawtech.com/drupal7/?q=content/how-create-mysql-triggers-execute-external-scriptphp-ubuntu-server-14

Comment: There is a simple way to execute a shell command from MySQL console: `\! command`

Comment: is not the same. With \! <command> syntax you escape the command and run it from the bash interpreter, but you can not use this syntax within a trigger or procedure, but is useful on many occasions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't a question, but an answer.

Comment: No need for a plugin, here's a simple example https://support.pubnub.com/hc/en-us/articles/360051973671-Can-I-publish-a-message-via-database-trigger-