# Ajax auto update when mysql update

Tags: javascript, php

Problem:

How can i get the message from mysql (Update message) , then it will auto update the record and display it in a real time??

I am searching about mysql trigger ( is that possible to call php file?)

can anyone help with this problem. thank you so much.

Comment: You almost certainly want to poll the database for changes rather than literally have the database trigger external programs.  This question discusses the issue in more depth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668666

Answer (score 1):

If you asking about the **Ajax call** then yeah we can do it, via **javascript**.

Here are some of the links of what Ajax is and why it is required:

1. [What is Ajax?](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)
2. [Wikipidea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Now coming to your question, **the question is actually incomplete** since you didn't posted any code or your effort to help us to understand what you want to achieve. So without any reference I want to tell that you can't call the **MySql Triggers** directly from the Javascript(as far as client side is concerned).

In order to call the D**B Mysql Triggers** you need any server side language that supports the connection between MySql and the language itself.

The Php is a language that supports that, you can read it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) & [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/create-mysql-trigger-in-php/).

A basic example of the Ajax is this that uses Jquery is :

```
$.ajax({
   url: "<where to post>",
   type: "POST",//type of posting the data
   data: <what to post>,
   success: function (data) {
     //what to do in success
   },
   error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
      //what to do in error
   },
   timeout : 15000//timeout of the ajax call
```

});

Now the **URL is the url on which your server is going to respond**, that is going to be the code of **Php call**.

Via above example you can call the server side call from anywhere of the UI on any particular event and that server call inside of it will trigger the MySql trigger, waits for trigger to get the result and will return the same/part of the data returned from the trigger back to the UI caller **success ()** callback.

Also the **vice versa is not possible easily**(as far as I know) in your case. Calling a php file from the **MySql trigger** is not that simple (or may be not possible) and requires extra effort and also is not recommended as well. So please **think a way around for your problem.**

**FYI:** *If you can write your own function/class in the php then it is better since you have better control on conditions and data rather than depending on the DB but yeah at the same time the speed is a bit slower in case you go for php implementation, so think smartly before implementing.*

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this by using mysql triggers. The MySQL trigger is a database object that is associated with a table. It will be activated when a defined action is executed for the table and do the defined task in MySQL domain only. You cannot execute a PHP or JS script with MySQL triggers.

For this you have to use Socket Programming in PHP.

[Socket Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php)