# Detect change from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I was using PHP robot that running 24/1 day for sending request to another server

At first I was thinking about checking for a new data to be send every 10 second, but it will be bad since there will be 8640 requests a day, and not to mention the size and amount of data that needed to parse, etc before sending it to another server

And I think is there any better way to detect changes on mysql and notify the PHP

Like when there is a new data, mysql send notify with unique id related to the new data

Answer (score 2):

You can use mysql trigger functions, maybe that can help.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

I belive you could have a file holding a count information, and with every request you could ask for the count of records for your query.

```
SELECT COUNT(?) FROM .....
```

If the count is higher than the last time a request was sent, the only thing you may do is subtract it, having this way, the number of changes. Then you can make another request looking only for the changes.

```
 SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT $numberOfChanges
```

I belive ID is autoincrement, this way, the changes will have the higher ID's

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Stack Overflow Question/Answer: 
[When a new row in database is added, an external command line program must be invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668666/when-a-new-row-in-database-is-added-an-external-command-line-program-must-be-in)

Create a MySQL trigger so that when new data is added, it updates a special table that only exists for holding this information.  Your cron job and/or php robot will check this table for information every 10 seconds.  If it has changes send that information to the other server and clean out the special table, otherwise end and wait for the next 10 seconds.